# why MYSQL Procedure returning NULL value even if the table contains matching data?

Tags: mysql, procedure

```
ID  CName
---------
101 India
102 Australia
103 Canada


DELIMITER \\
create procedure getCountry(in val varchar(20), out ctry varchar(20))
begin
    select Country.CName into ctry from test.Country where Country.CName like CONCAT('%',@val,'%');
end;


call getCountry('aus',@ctr);
select @ctr;
```

why @ctr showning my NULL value even if my table contains India !! same is the case when i pass 'aus' in calling the procedure!! please help

Comment: You Haven't set @val - you have val as a paramter.

Comment: @P.Salmon how to set '@val' ? i'm new to procedures. so can you please give me full code regarding my question... really appreciated

Comment: Seriously?- I don't think I could have given you a bigger hint.